# python mysql connector - What is the right way for multiple queries

Tags: python, mysql, mysql-connector

```
import mysql.connector
cnx=mysql.connector.connect(user,password,host,database)
cursor=(cnx.cursor)
```

and, i am trying to query the database twice with different queries as below

```
query1result=[]
query2result=[]

cursor.execute(query1)
for each in cursor:
    query1result.append[each]
cursor.execute(query1)
for each in cursor:
    query1result.append[each]
```

I get an error at python/mysql/connector/cursor.py. line 474

I want to know what is the right way for multiple queries.

Comment: it would be more helpful if you paste the entire error and relevant code snippet.

Comment: my bad. when i run cursor.execute(query1) and
cursor.execute(query2.) without for loop in between i get that error. When i put the for loop there is no error.  But i remember getting  similar errors before. so wanted to know if there is a right way to execute consequetive queries one after other. Like if i store each query in a variable.

Comment: What is the error?! "it would be more helpful if you paste the entire error" - this means the full stacktrace!

Comment: Line 6 in <module> cursor.execute ("my query").     File "c:\python27\lib\site-packages\mysql\connector\cursor.py" line 476, in execute.   raise errors.InternalError("unread result found")

Comment: The ideal way would be to have individual SQL commands within separate `cursor.execute(parameter_1, parameter_2)` statements. You can `connection.commit()` to execute all statements on db.

Answer (score 5):

found it here:

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-python/en/connector-python-example-cursor-transaction.html

the same would be for querying too..